# Json return value show from Angular Js

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

Angular Js Script

---

```
this.http.post(url, body, options)
  .subscribe((data) =>
  {
     if(data.status === 200)
     {
        this.hideForm   = true;
        this.sendNotification(console.log(data.meesage));
     }
  });
```

### PHP Code

How to get json_encode success message through this.sendNotification()

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO eastcost_school_room(school_room_name, created) VALUES(:name, Now())";
        $stmt    = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was added to the database'));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

map the response before subscribing

```
this.http.post(url, body, options)
  .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  .subscribe((data) =>
  {
     if(data.status === 200)
     {
        this.hideForm   = true;
        this.sendNotification(console.log(data.meesage));
     }
  });
```

Comment: Declaration or statement expected.

.map((res:Response) => res.json());
   .subscribe((data) =>
   {

Comment: import this `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: Same problem after import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Answer (score 0):

Php  code

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO eastcost_school_room(school_room_name, created) VALUES(:name, Now())";
        $stmt    = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

            $response["success"] = 1;  


            $response["message"] = 'Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was added to the database';  

            // echoing JSON response  

            echo json_encode($response);
```

Post method in the api service class

Service

```
insert(parameters): Observable<any> {

            return this.http.post('url', body, {
                headers: headers

            })
                .map((res: any) => res.json())

        }
```

And subscribe the response from your class

```
this.service.insert(parameters)
      .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);

        if (response.success == "1") {

                      console.log("Successfull login");

        }
        else {
          alert(" Invalid user");



        }


      },
      error => {
        alert(error);
      }
      );
```

Comment: error showing property 'success' does not exists on type 'response '

Comment: success is the Boolean that is included in your php code.  Check the line            $response["success"] = 1;

Comment: @Andyrob did you get the response on console.log(response);

Comment: Yes Response showing undefined when I put  alert(console.log(response));